# Cannot find extension php_mssql.dll

Tags: php, macos, xampp

I tried to push my site live yesterday, but I keep getting this error:

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Core Warning
>
> Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library'/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_mssql.dll' /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_mssql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: Unknown
>
> Line Number: 0
>
> Backtrace:

I am on my Mac I am using XAMMP with PHP 5.5.24 & 5.6.8 versions. I have when into the extension file and uncommented a few things and I was able to get mySQL database working but I could not get this error to go away.

Comment: yeah you're right, removed my comment

Answer (score 0):

The php_mssql.dll is used by PHP to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database.

If you are not using a Microsoft SQL Server database then comment out the extension for php_mssql.dll in the php.ini file

Comment: Ok so I'm kinda new to all of this stuff so forgive me if what I am going to ask seems straight forward. We I first pushed everything live extension=php_mssql.dll and extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll were commented out. If I try and comment it out and it still doesn't work what should I do?

Comment: Ok so you are editing the wrong php.ini, there are normally 2 per system 1 for PHP CLI and one for the PHP used by APache.. Look for the other one

Comment: The one for APache would be in the Xampp files correct? If so this is the one I have been editing.

Comment: It would be in the xampp\apache\bin folder and not in the xampp\php folder

Comment: So I searched my whole computer, and it looks like I do not have an Apache folder that has bin in it at all. I've tried uninstalling and installing, and the same thing happen. I'm not sure why I'm having so much trouble with this.